# Factories in Java

Tags: java, factory

I'm learning factories concept in Java, and I have one question because most of the Java tutorial suggest implementing factory like this:

```java
public class factory1 {

    public static Dao getDao(Object entity) {
        if (entity instanceof E_Competence) {
            return new JpaDaoCompetence();
        }
        if (entity instanceof E_Categorie) {
            return new JpaDaoCategorie();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown entity type.");
        }
    }
}
```

But I would have tended to do it like that:

```java
public class factory2 {

    public static Dao getDao(E_Competence entity) {
        return new JpaDaoCompetence();
    }

    public static Dao getDao(E_Categorie entity) {
        return new JpaDaoCategorie();
    }
}
```

I would like to know which is the best way to do and why.

Comment: the former is more generic for the caller method, so it no need explicit type conversion. though none of the two make sense to me.

Comment: What would be the point of having a method that takes an argument but doesn't use it? If using two methods, just give them two different names?

Comment: The second form puts the decision responsibility on the caller of the factory.  In general, the factory pattern is more useful if, when different types are possible, the factory is the single place making the decision.  But it has to be said that the factory pattern is much overused.  If a simple `new Thing(...)` would suffice, why bother?

Comment: The second solution only works when at compile time the type is known to resolve the method. The first will work for any type (though generally you might use a more specific base-interface or class instead of `Object`).

Answer (score 1):

**It depends**

Sometimes you want to have one factory per type you are producing. Sometimes you have a whole inheritance hierarchy of factories. Sometimes you have a factory like you are showing, that can produce different objects.

Sometimes your second example works. And sometimes it doesn't, and you need the first one.

The issue comes when whatever calls the factory methods doesn't know itself what type `entity` is. In that case the compiler can't know which of the two methods is being called. Could happen if there is a lot of indirection, for example.